# Drawing an image on the canvas in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have been trying to get an image drawn on the canvas however have failed to do so. The HTML code simply creates the canvas element "canvas1" with no additional processing.

Here is the JS:

```
function loadlogo(){
    var logo = new Image();
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    //resize the canvas to the current window
    context.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    context.canvas.height = window.innerHeight / 3;
    logo.src = "images/1.png";
    logo.onload = function() {context.drawImage(logo,0,0;};
    context.shadowOffsetX = 50;
    context.shadowOffsetY = 30;
    context.shadowColor = "pink";
    }

    window.addEventListener("load",loadlogo,false);
    window.addEventListener("resize",loadlogo,false);
```

Any help you could give would be awesome!!!
I have tried this many ways and am stuck.

Thanks,
Bryan

Answer (score 1):

Put your onload function for img before you assign img src

Answer (score 0):

Change this part

```
{context.drawImage(logo,0,0;};
                           ^ Notice the missing end-parenthesis here
```

to

```
{context.drawImage(logo,0,0)};
```

I would as QBM5 also recommend to put the `src` after setting `onload` to be sure it's properly initialized.